# Modificar elemento HTML desde el script de la extensión sin clicar en el icono

Tags: javascript, extensión-google-chrome

Pues tengo esta función en JavaScript que rellena un elemento 'input' con un texto:

```
async function fillInput2Factor() {
chrome.tabs.query({ 'active': true, 'lastFocusedWindow': true }, function (tabs) {
    var url = tabs[0].url;
    if (url.includes(URL)) {
        chrome.scripting.executeScript({
            target: { tabId: tabs[0].id },
            function: (codigoExtension) => {
                const input2Factor = document.getElementById('input2factor');
                input2Factor.value = codigoExtension;
            },
            args: [codigo]
        });
    }
}); 
}
```

La función como tal funciona bien, pero sólo al pulsar en el icono de la extensión. Me preguntaba si hay alguna forma de hacer que se ejecute cada 30s (por ejemplo) **sin tener que pulsar en el icono**. Soy nuevo haciendo extensiones en Chrome, pero por lo que he investigado, no sé si se podría hacer con un `Service Worker`.

**EDIT:**
Intento ejecutar `fillInput2Factor()` cada 30s sincronizado con la generación del código TOTP así:

```
async function updateCounterAndGenerate() {
const now = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);
const nextIntervalStart = Math.ceil(now / interval) * interval;
const secondsRemaining = nextIntervalStart - now;
contador.textContent = `Reinicio en: ${secondsRemaining}s`;

if (secondsRemaining === 0) {
    // Si los segundos restantes son 0, genera un nuevo código
    generarTOTP();
    updateCodigo();
    fillInput2Factor();
}
}
```

Y luego:

```
setInterval(updateCounterAndGenerate, 1000);
```

Comment: No entiendo el problema de fondo, si has rellenado el elemento input una primera vez, que caso tiene volver a rellenarlo 30s más tarde ???

Comment: Generalmente valdría con rellenarlo una vez pero puede que justo expire el código y quiero que se ponga el nuevo. De todas formas lo que querría saber es como hacer para que la función fillInput2Factor() se ejecute en segundo plano y el input se rellene al entrar en la página (porque está diseñada la extensión para una página en concreto) sin tener que clicar en el icono de la extensión.

Answer (score 0):

Si puedes utilizar el 'setInterval()' que es una funciona incorporada ya de JavaScript que te permite ejecutar la función cada un cierto tiempo si lo que quieres es ejecutar el código que esta dentro de la función puedes hacerlo así:

```
async function fillInput2Factor() {
    setInterval(() => {
        chrome.tabs.query({ 'active': true, 'lastFocusedWindow': true }, function (tabs) {
            var url = tabs[0].url;
            if (url.includes(URL)) {
                chrome.scripting.executeScript({
                    target: { tabId: tabs[0].id },
                    function: (codigoExtension) => {
                        const input2Factor = document.getElementById('input2factor');
                        input2Factor.value = codigoExtension;
                    },
                    args: [codigo]
                });
            }
        }); 
    }, 30000);
}
```

El ultimo parámetro que ves son los milisegundos 30000 equivalen a 30 segundos.

Por ultimo si lo que quieres es que se ejecute toda la función cada un cierto tiempo saca el setInerval fuera simplemente del 'async function fillInput2Factor() {'

Comment: Claro, el setInterval() lo uso para generar un código 2FA puesto que la extensión va de eso. Ya probé a ejecutar fillInput2Factor() dentro de la función que genera el 2FA y así todo está sincronizado cada 30s, pero no funciona. El código si se genera cada 30s, pero lo que es rellenar el <input> no lo hace. Mira el edit.